# Checkout file from the commit using cnext

Tags: git, vim, vim-fugitive

So I've been using `vim fugitive` plugin and I find the `Glog` and `cnext` feature great to see how the file has changed over time.

I would like to checkout the file from the commit I've navigated to using the `cnext` command. Is it possible to do so?

Comment: with the revision open, try `Gwrite`, please report if this is what you want

Comment: @Kent it opens the `HEAD`.

Comment: How about asking to the plugin's author?

Answer (score 1):

If the plugin doesn't provide corresponding command, hope this function helps.

Press `gc` when in the `quickfix` window of file commit logs.

```
autocmd FileType qf nnoremap<buffer> gc :call GitCheckoutFile()<cr>

function! GitCheckoutFile()
    let l = getline('.')
    if match(l, '\vfugitive:\\\\') != -1
        let path = substitute(l, '\v(fugitive:\\\\)|(\|.*)', '', 'g')

        let commit_id = matchstr(path, '\v.git\\\\\zs\w*\ze\\')
        let commit_info = matchstr(path, '\v.git\\\\\w*\\')
        let file = substitute(path, escape(commit_info, '\'), '', 'g')

        execute 'Git checkout '.commit_id.' -- '.file
    endif
endfunction
```

Comment: I think it would be easier to leverage fugitive. Get a buffer's revision via `matchstr(fugitive#buffer().rev(), '\x\{40}')` and the file path via `fugitive@buffer().path()`

Comment: Year, It's better to leverage fugitive.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to simply copy/yank the buffer you are currently on and then replace the current version with this recently yanked copy.

```
:%y|Gedit|%d_|put|0d_|w
```

However if you rather do this via `:Gread` commands you can do the following:

```
:execute "Gedit|Gread! show " . matchstr(fugitive#buffer().rev(), '\x\{40}') . ":". fugitive#buffer().path()
```

You may want to wrap one of these up into a mapping or command if you do this often.

Comment: It's a much simpler solution. `shellescape` seems to casue error to the final command for my case. And typo: the second `fugtive`.